# Parameter extraction of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, cmos, modeling, reference-materials

I need to extract the parameters of MOSFET to study how  all these parameters are getting affected by stress on silicon chips.

If you guyz have good reference from which I can look into this topic?

Comment: A real physical MOSFET?

Comment: Maybe start with the parameters inside a MOSFET datasheet.

Comment: I think you need a good book on modelling MOSFETs. Make sure it covers parameter extraction. Ask your coworkers to recommend a good book.

Comment: A big point of an internship is to learn from the experts at the company. If you have someone mentoring you there, it would probably be most valuable to turn to them first for questions, especially open-ended questions like this.

Comment: Yes I have started with one book and it is a real MOSFET.Thank you for taking a time and replying my question.

Comment: It this what you are looking for?  https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup170/slup170.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need an introductory reference into the topic of parameter extraction in general. For that I would recommend "Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE" from Massobrio and Antognetti. The newest edition (2nd Ed. from 1993) doesn't contain any newer developments but it's second to none as an introduction into the topic in general and contains information on MOSFET parameter extraction in particular. You can check out the Table of Contents [here](http://www.gbv.de/dms/ilmenau/toc/123145619.PDF). You can find a more advanced treatment of MOSFET parameter modeling and parameter extraction [in this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-7091-9247-4) ("MOSFET Models for VLSI Circuit Simulation" from Arora)

If you're interested in Power MOSFETs I can recommend in addition to check out Chapter 4 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-90-481-8614-3) ("Compact Modeling" edited by Gildenblat)